# searching a particular setter programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, styles

is it possible to search a particular setter, rather than iterating through the collection and doing something like this.

```
  foreach (Setter setter in dataRecord.Cells[i].Field.Settings.EditorStyle.Setters)
  {
    if (setter.Property.Name == "Format")
    {
      excelWorkSheetRow.Cells[i + level].CellFormat.FormatString = setter.Value.ToString();
      break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SetterBaseCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.setterbasecollection_methods.aspx) doesn't provide any methods beyond those inherited from Collection<>.  You can use the FindFirstOrDefault extension method to retrieve the setter you want like this:

```
var formatSetter=dataRecord.Cells[i].EditorStyle.Setters.OfType<Setter>()
    .FirstOrDefault(setter=>setter.Property.Name == "Format");
if (formatSetter!=null)
...
```

The trick is that SetterBaseCollection can contain both Setter and EventSetter object. Only Setter objects have the Property ... property, so you need OfType<> to search only the Setter objects. Your code would break if anyone ever added an event setter to the style.

Answer (score 0):

If your object supports the IEnumerable interface, you could use the Where() method.

Have a look at the following [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) for an example